# ffmpeg showing null when i am trying using php file

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4

Here is the output ffmpeg path in server

```
root@server.rkv.igq.mybluehost.me [~]# whereis ffmpeg

ffmpeg: /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg /usr/include/ffmpeg /usr/share/ffm peg /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz /usr/src/ffmpegscript/ffmpeg
```

When I am trying to run command (ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 sample.avi) using SSH it is working fine but when I am trying using PHP it is not working. Here is my PHP code:

```php
include 'usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/';
var_dump(shell_exec('ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 sample.avi'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with simple command like :

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

If that does not work I think you should try this: h`ttps://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg`  requires ffmpeg installd + ffprobe.